# Get the ID of an added file

Tags: php, post, mysqli

I have the following table called filescontent

```
ID  |  version  |  fileContent  | ownerID
```

I need to get the ID of the file which is added by the user with a POST request and then I have to manipulte it. I'm using PHP and MySQLi.

Comment: Sure thing we can! Where is the code you have tried so far?

Comment: can you paste your code?

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_insert_id() should do the trick.

Be careful to ensure that no other query has been placed between the insert query that you want the id of, and you calling this function, as this would result in you getting the id of the wrong file.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

if($_POST) {

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_FILES['uploadFile']['name']);

```
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, file_get_contents($_FILES ['uploadFile']['tmp_name']));

    $select_version = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT version FROM filescontent ORDER BY fileID DESC LIMIT 1");
    $fetch_version = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_version);
    $increment_version = $fetch_version['version'] + 1;
    echo '<br>'.$increment_version .' версия';

    $select_fileID = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT fileID FROM filescontent ORDER BY fileID DESC LIMIT 1");
    $fetch_fileID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_fileID);
    $increment_fileID = $fetch_fileID["fileID"] + 1;
    echo '<br>'. $increment_fileID.'ID';

    $selectName = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT fileName FROM files WHERE fileName='$name'");
    $fetchName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectName);
    $fetchName = $fetchName['fileName'];

    $selectIDname= "SELECT fileID FROM files WHERE fileName = '$name'";
    $selectIDnameQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $selectIDname);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectIDnameQuery);
    $selectIDname = $row['fileID'];
    echo '<br><pre>'.print_r($row, true).'</pre>';

    $addedFileID = '';
    $selectAddedFile = "SELECT fileID FROM filescontent WHERE fileID='$addedFileID'";

    $a = mysqli_error($connection);
    echo '<br>'.$a.'<br>';  

    if(!strcmp($name, $fetchName)){
        echo 'The file exists';
        $query1 = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO filescontent (fileID, version, fileContent, author) VALUES ('$selectIDname', '$increment_version', '$data', 2)");
    }
    else{
        echo 'The file does not exist'; 
        $query2= mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO filescontent (fileID, version, fileContent, author) VALUES ('$increment_fileID', 1, '$data', 2)");
        $query3 = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO files (fileID, fileName, ownerID) VALUES ('$increment_fileID', '$name', 2)");
    }

    $a = mysqli_error($connection);
    echo '<br>'.$a.'<br>';  
}
```